# expected unqualified-id before ‘{’ token in boost example

Tags: boost

I picked (ie copy-pasted) the following example from Boost documentation (http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0b1/libs/assign/doc/index.html#operator+=):

```
#include <boost/assign/std/vector.hpp> // for 'operator+=()'
#include <boost/assert.hpp> 
using namespace std;
using namespace boost::assign; // bring 'operator+=()' into scope

{
    vector<int> values;  
    values += 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9; // insert values at the end of the container
    BOOST_ASSERT( values.size() == 9 );
    BOOST_ASSERT( values[0] == 1 );
    BOOST_ASSERT( values[8] == 9 );
}
```

Which throws the following error:

```
$ g++ boost_assign.cpp
boost_assign.cpp:6:1: error: expected unqualified-id before ‘{’ token
 {
 ^
```

What's wrong ? Are the boost examples not directly copy-paste-run-able ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those examples are not copy-paste-run-able. Code enclosed in braces needs to be pasted somewhere in a function.